# Creating a dictionary from CSV using python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have a CSV of the format

[image]

where A, B & C are the headers.

How do I pythonically convert this CSV into a dictionary of the following form

```
{'A': '1', 'B': '4','C': '7'},
{'A': '2', 'B': '5','C': '8'},
{'A': '3', 'B': '6','C': '9'}
```

So far I'm trying the following code:

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open('file.csv'))

result = {}
for row in reader:
    for column, value in row.items():
        result.setdefault(column, []).append(value)
```

This is not giving me the intended output. Any suggestions?

Comment: Expected result looks like a list of dicts but the attempt shows an outer dict. What should the keys be in this dict?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The extra code you have is unnecessary. `csv` already does the heavy-lifting for you. Just use `csv.DictReader` as is:

```
import csv

with open('e.txt') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

The above outputs:

```
OrderedDict([('A', '1'), (' B', ' 4'), (' C', ' 7')])
OrderedDict([('A', '2'), (' B', ' 5'), (' C', ' 8')])
OrderedDict([('A', '3'), (' B', ' 6'), (' C', ' 9')])
```

You may think you want a `dict` rather than an `OrderedDict`, but I'm fairly sure you don't. Using an `OrderedDict` object will ensure that your rows stay ordered correctly.

> thank you for your reply. This seems to work but for my task, I need it in the format mentioned in the question. Is there a way to turn it into that format?

Why exactly? Don't be fooled by the format. `OrderedDict` *behaves the **exact*** same as a normally dictionary. The only difference is that `OrderedDict` will maintain its order. If all you need is to print your rows in a certain format, you can convert each row to a `dict` and use it's `__repr__`:

```
for row in reader:
    print(dict(row))
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. This seems to work but for my task, I need it in the format mentioned in the question. Is there a way to turn it into that format?

Comment: @kage77 I update my answer to address your concerns.

Comment: Thank you @ChristianDean I’ll keep your advice in mind and modify my code!