# Load google sheet csv as dictionary in python

Tags: python, google-sheets

I have a public google sheet with 2 sheets https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14hFn00O9632n96Z2xGWvfrcY-K4kHiOGR02Rx7dsj54/edit#gid=447738801 
I know how to wget this as a csv (if it had only 1 sheet), but is there a simple way of getting sheet 1 and sheet 2 as a dictionary or as a csv file (each sheet as 1 csv file) and I will parse it. 
`gid` of both sheets are different

In the end I will have header as key and values below the header as values

Comment: You can't have multiple values per key, unless the values are in a list.

Comment: ohh, yes then I dont know how we can keep them as a list :( header being the key and other column as value of the header which is a list)

Comment: using pandas for the additional things to be done after file is downloaded, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `requests` library to download each sheet, and write the response content to a file.

Working implementation:

```
import requests

sheets = {
    'sheet1': 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14hFn00O9632n96Z2xGWvfrcY-K4kHiOGR02Rx7dsj54/export?format=csv&id=14hFn00O9632n96Z2xGWvfrcY-K4kHiOGR02Rx7dsj54&gid=0',
    'sheet2': 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/14hFn00O9632n96Z2xGWvfrcY-K4kHiOGR02Rx7dsj54/export?format=csv&id=14hFn00O9632n96Z2xGWvfrcY-K4kHiOGR02Rx7dsj54&gid=447738801'
} 

for sheet in list(sheets.keys()):
    response = requests.get(sheets[sheet])
    with open(f'{sheet}.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
        csvfile.write(response.content)
```

This will save each sheet in a file (`sheet1.csv` and `sheet2.csv` in this case). Note that I got the link for each sheet just by downloading it as CSV from a browser and copying the download link.

You can then convert it to a dictionary using the CSV library. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943126/creating-a-dictionary-from-csv-using-python).

Comment: Thanks @glhr it mostly solves my purpose, Do we have a way to keep the response.content in memory only (and not write file to disk and then read it again to create a dict). TIA

Comment: It's possible, put please explain in your post how you would like the data to be formatted in a dictionary exactly (eg. do you want a dictionary for each row?).

Comment: added to the post, each cloumn header is a key and values below it are its values, was trying `flike = io.StringIO(response.text)`  then `for row in csv.reader(flike):`

Answer (score 0):

Just use pandas to load CSV. Then you can convert into Dict or anything else later

```
import pandas as pd 
# Read data from file 'filename.csv' 
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv") 

data.to_dict('series')
```